# Duplicated files and folder in bundle

Tags: angularjs, symfony, bundle

I'm working on AngularJS App with Symfony where in the src folder I have HTML and JS files that are duplicated in the web folder. I don't know how to automatically generate those files.

Example this file located in

```
D:\e-electricity.com\web\bundles\ubidelectricity\js\front\Post\PostFrontCtrl.js
```

and in

```
D:\e-electricity.com\src\ContinuousNet\UbidElectricityBundle\Resources\public\js\front\Post\PostFrontCtrl.js
```

And this HTML file :

```
D:\e-electricity.com\src\ContinuousNet\UbidElectricityBundle\Resources\public\js\front\Post\post.html
D:\e-electricity.com\web\bundles\ubidelectricity\js\front\Post\post.html
```

Comment: I don't have any idea about how symfony builds an app! But it seems like one of the basic principles in that procedure. You may want to look at Symfony's docs again.

Comment: You would either be using WebPack Encore, Assets, or Assetic. Symfony deprecated Assetic in favor of using Webpack Encore as it is more versatile. Assets are automatically copied from `Bundle/Resources/views/public` into your declared `/web` directory when executing `composer.phar install/update` so that those files can be accessed in the browser.

Comment: For more details see the Symfony Documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/best_practices/web-assets.html and the component details at https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/asset.html